# Функция фильтрации массива, с помощью вспомогательной функции

Tags: javascript

Есть код функции "filter" для фильтрации массива "arr", согласно результатов выполнения функции "func".

```
function filter(arr, func) {
   var result = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       var val = arr[i];
       if (func(val)) {
       result.push(val);
       }
   }

   return result;
}

function inBetween(a, b) {
    return function(x) {
    return x >= a && x <= b;
    };
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
alert( filter(arr, inBetween(3, 6)) ); // 3,4,5,6
```

Объясните пожалуйста, как `val=arr[i]` передается в `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Функция `inBetween` возвращает новую функцию с одним аргументом `x`. Новая функция замыкается на две переменных `a` и `b`, которые есть аргументы `inBetween`.

То есть после вызова `inBetween(3, 6)` у нас появляется новая анонимная функция, которая выглядела бы так:

```
function(x) {

    return x >= 3 && x <= 6;
}
```

Эту новую функцию мы передаем в `filter(/* тут массив */, /* тут новая функция */)`

```
function filter(arr, func) {

   var result = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       var val = arr[i];

       if (func(val)) {
           result.push(val);
       }

       /* Здесь надо помнить, что func - сейчас та самая новая функция
          с одним аргументом х.
          Так как val у нас равен arr[i], а val мы передаем в качестве аргумента
          к func, получается, что arr[i] попадает в х */
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. То есть условие    `if(func(val))`    можно трактовать так, если функция  "func", имеет аргумент "val" и результатом работы `func(val)`,    является некое значение, отличное в логическом смысле от "false", добавить в массив "result", элемент, со значением "val".

Comment: Чуть-чуть по-другому: если результат вызова функции `func` с аргументом `val` является некое значение, отличное в логическом смысле от "false", добавить в массив "result", элемент, со значением "val"

Answer (score 2):

Функция `inBetween` возвращает замыкание `(closure)` - она-же анонимная функция внутри `inBetween`. В ее области видимости имеются входящие в нее параметры `a` и `b`, которые позволяют проводить проверку числа `x`. Сама функция `filter` принимает массив первым аргументом и `callback`-функцию с помощью которой проводится фильтрация элементов массива.